# Dual Booting and "locking" hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I don't think this question has been posted yet, but I'm planning on dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on two drives, a solid state and a mechanical respectively. Is there a way to disable the SSD Windows is on when using Ubuntu? I have a partition on the mechanical disk I intend to use for Ubuntu, and I don't want to see my SSD on Ubuntu once it's installed. So disabling my SSD for Ubuntu is what I'm getting at. Is there a way so it doesn't ruin each OS's drive functions?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mount the partitions on your SSD, your Ubuntu system will not allow any modification to them, so there's really no action you should take aside from avoiding mounting those partitions, but since the volume label of mountable partitions is always present on the left menu of any `nautilus`' window, if you fear you could accidentally mount such partitions by clicking on their menu entry, you could hide them from `nautilus`' menu: in `Disks`:

- Select the SSD drive on the left menu
- Select the first partition you want to hide on the right menu
- Click on the icon showing two gears below the selected partition and choose "Edit mount options"
- Toggle the "Automatic mount options" switch to "Off" if set to "On"
- Untick "Show in user interface"
- Repeat for each partition you wish to hide.

Comment: So if I want to disable the SSD, like disabling a drive entirely from being used in Ubuntu, then I'd do this? If I do this, would it disable in Windows as well or is it independent?

Comment: @Infiltratist You're not "disabling" the drive, you are preventing drive partition's volume names from showing into `nautilus`' windows, avoiding to accidentally mount them into Ubuntu, which is the only thing which *could* change something on the device, in all other cases your drive will stay untouched